# How to align 2 content blocks horizontally in css without using <table>s

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to get 2 content blocks together horizontally. I do not want to use `<table>` to achieve this.

**I have this markup:**

```
<div class="left-side float-left">Scope:</div>
<div class="right-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut porta lacus. Vestibulum dapibus pulvinar tellus sit amet commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</div>
```

**The objective:** to get the right-side content block to ***not wrap*** around the left-side content block on smaller viewports (in responsive design).

**CSS I've tried:**

```
.left-side,
.right-side {
    /*float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    /*width: 50px;*/
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: looks like you're missing a period on 'float-left'. I assume it should be '.float-left'

Comment: Ok, thanks @SamHuckaby .. I cleaned-up my OQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your markup, just one line of CSS is enough to achieve this through `flexbox`. Wrap both the items inside a parent container. Set `display: flex` to parent element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left-side {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side float-left">Scope:</div>
  <div class="right-side">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut porta lacus. Vestibulum dapibus pulvinar tellus sit amet commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I want @ManojKumar -- I'l give it a try

Comment: I don't know the OP requirements but this wont work in IE9.

Comment: Yes. It won't work in <=IE9. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox but supports all major browsers otherwise and it is the way to go from 2015.

Comment: It works perfectly and cleanly...thanks @ManojKumar. I really don't care about IE9 and below. Users with those browsers are not in my site's target group.

Comment: I guess what is an issue with *this solution* is that it does not work in Safari on an iPhone -- but I can live with it.

Comment: make sure you prefix it with -webkit- for Safari. Safari 9 removes the need for a prefix, but thats still a while away.

Answer (score 2):

Calc is fairly well supported at this point.

```
width: calc( 100% - 50px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2j3nLqo/1/

You can set the `.right-side` to use this :

```
.right-side {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc( 100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try @ericjbasti

Comment: Your fiddle works just as I need my page to work. I'll work on incorporating it into my css and post back.

Comment: I tried it in my markup and css and it does not work there...not sure exactly why

Comment: Yeah it should work fine, I actually just did this for a current project. You'll want to make 100% sure that the first column is only taking up the 50px. If its extending beyond that for some reason it will break.

Comment: I guess what is an issue with *this solution* is that it does not work in Safari on an iPhone

Comment: It's worked on iOS Safari since 6, so that shouldn't be an issue. If for some reason you can't be 100% sure what elements calculated width (margin+border+padding+width) will be, it does become less useful.